# Redirect IE6 to a different website on Wordpress

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, browser, wordpress

IE6 is not supported my the new theme I am using on my Wordpress website. How can I redirect them to my old website?

Comment: Ignore them. It's well beyond time for them to upgrade and they're a tiny fraction of internet traffic at this point.

Comment: @ceejayoz I agree but this is a business website, and everyone under IE 9 can't view it that could be a big problem.

Comment: Have you consulted your stats? The vast majority of businesses stuck on an IE version are stuck on either 7 or 8. Why do you say "everyone under IE9 can't view it", your question said IE6 and below?

Comment: @user377065 No I was just using that as an example, only IE9 and above works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_Comments):

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
```

---

[codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Comment_CSS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Comment_CSS)